# Cannot run vscode extension starter project tests twice in a row on macos

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am implementing a VSCode extension and I have set up the project following [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).

It creates a starter project and with it a `src/test/runTest.ts`:

```
import * as path from 'path';

import { runTests } from '@vscode/test-electron';

async function main() {
    try {
        // The folder containing the Extension Manifest package.json
        // Passed to `--extensionDevelopmentPath`
        const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');

        // The path to test runner
        // Passed to --extensionTestsPath
        const extensionTestsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './suite/index');

        // Download VS Code, unzip it and run the integration test
        await runTests({ extensionDevelopmentPath, extensionTestsPath });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to run tests');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

and a `package.json`:

```json
{
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
}
```

---

I cannot run

```
npm test
```

twice in a row.

---

The first time, everything goes well, and it looks like it is downloading VSCode in the folder `.vscode-test`.

```
Downloading VS Code 1.65.2 from https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.65.2/darwin/stable
Downloading VS Code [==============================] 100%Downloaded VS Code 1.65.2 into /my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2
```

However, I get a warning:

```
WARNING: IPC handle "/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/user-data/1.65.2-main.sock" is longer than 103 chars, try a shorter --user-data-dir
```

When I run the tests a second time, if fails:

```
Found existing install in /my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2. Skipping download
WARNING: IPC handle "/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/user-data/1.65.2-main.sock" is longer than 103 chars, try a shorter --user-data-dir
[main 2022-03-29T14:44:22.271Z] Could not delete obsolete instance handle Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/user-data/1.65.2-main.sock'
    at unlinkSync (original-fs.js:1210:3)
    at ne.claimInstance (/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:77:5083)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async /my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:77:2282
    at async ne.startup (/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:77:2151) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'unlink',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/user-data/1.65.2-main.sock'
}
[main 2022-03-29T14:44:22.274Z] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/user-data/1.65.2-main.sock'
    at unlinkSync (original-fs.js:1210:3)
    at ne.claimInstance (/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:77:5083)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async /my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:77:2282
    at async ne.startup (/my-path/my-project/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-1.65.2/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:77:2151)
Exit code:   1
Failed to run tests
```

But it works fine if I delete the folder `.vscode-test`.

What is happening and what can I do?

Comment: It's unclear to me why running your tests downloads VS Code. Where does this coming from? The scripts in package.json at least contain no command to download VS Code.

Comment: I guess this is because of the library `@vscode/test-electron`. I supposed it downloads a version of VSCode that can run tests. That doesn't shock me too much as I will expect my test to run on CI pipelines at some points.

Comment: OK, I see, that's the same as with Selenium. You are doing GUI tests there, right?

Comment: Not yet, I'm honestly not too clear on what will be the scope of the tests yet as I just started. But I guess I some point I'll do some GUI tests yeah

Comment: @ValentinVignal Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No I didn't @Gunnar

Answer (score 3):

try to make your work directory shorter
or
use the os temporary directory

for example:

```
await runTests({ 
  extensionDevelopmentPath, 
  extensionTestsPath,
  launchArgs: ['--user-data-dir', `${os.tmpdir()}`]
});
```